# postgresql LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, postgresql, openldap

I am trying to give an LDAP authentication to my postgresql database.

Here is my pg_hba.conf config file

```
local all all md5
local all postgres md5
host  all all   0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver=myldap_serverip ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", ou=users, dc=example, dc=hyd, dc=com"
```

But when i am trying to connect with one of my LDAP user called test, i am getting the following error:

```
psql -U test
Password for user test:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test"
```

Note: I have created test user in postgresql.

I performed the below search and it is working

```
ldapsearch -W -D "cn=test user,ou=users,dc=example,dc=hyd,dc=com" -b "dc=example,dc=hyd,dc=com" "uid=test"
```

Comment: psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U test 
Password for user test:
psql: FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "test"
FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "test

Comment: What do the postgresql and ldap server logs tell you?

Comment: 2015-01-14 08:58:03 UTC LOG:  LDAP login failed for user "cn=test,ou=users,dc=example,dc=hyd,dc=com" on server "serverip": Invalid credentials
2015-01-14 08:58:03 UTC FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "test"

Comment: I am using the same credentials to establish a ssh connection and i am able to login.

Comment: Recent error:  2015-01-14 09:22:00 UTC LOG:  could not perform initial LDAP bind for ldapbinddn "cn=test user,ou=users,dc=example,dc=hyd,dc=com" on server "serverip": Server is unwilling to perform
2015-01-14 09:22:00 UTC FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "test"
2015-01-14 09:22:00 UTC DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 16: "host   all   test   0.0.0.0/0   ldap ldapserver=serverip ldapbasedn="dc=example,dc=hyd,dc=com" ldapbinddn="cn=test user,ou=users,dc=example,dc=hyd,dc=com""

Comment: LDAP logs:   Jan 14 09:30:20 localhost slapd[3174]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uidNumber) not indexed
Jan 14 09:30:43 localhost slapd[3174]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
Jan 14 09:32:28 localhost slapd[3174]: message repeated 24 times: [ <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed]
Jan 14 09:32:40 localhost slapd[3174]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (cn) not indexed
Jan 14 09:32:40 localhost slapd[3174]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
Jan 14 09:32:40 localhost slapd[3174]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (memberUid) not indexed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're testing the LDAP bind with a different dn than what postgres constructs:

```
cn=test user,ou=users,dc=example,dc=hyd,dc=com
```

vs

```
"cn=" + "test" + ", ou=users, dc=example, dc=hyd, dc=com"
```

i.e. "test" doesn't match "test user"

Comment: Can you please let me know in this statement what you want me to change.    host  all all   0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver=myldap_serverip ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", ou=users, dc=example, dc=hyd, dc=com"

Comment: Great thanks a ton... You are a gem it is working fine now.